# THH and string topology

Tags: homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, string-topology

There is an equivalence $THH(S^{\infty}_+ LX) = S^{\infty}_+ FX$ where $FX$ is the free loop space (I already used the letter $L$). The circle action on $THH$ gives rise to a degree $1$ cyclic differential operator on $H_*(FX)$. This is one of the operations considered by Chas-Sullivan. Can we explain the other string topology operations using $THH$?

There's also a circle action on $THH(R)$ where $R$ is any $E_{\infty}$-ring. Are there string topology operations here?

Comment: Note that in this case the circle action on $THH$ agrees with the one on the free loop space by precomposition. (By the way, why call the loop space $L$ and not $\Omega$ ? Then $L$ for free loop space) But that's a very interesting question !